# How to check the file is download on button click using code first api

Tags: code-first, coded-ui-tests

I am using code first api for UI Automation. 
I want to check whether file is downloaded or not  on button click.

I am able to find the button and click is working fine .
i dont know how to check the file is downloaded or not.

I am new to this technology. sorry if it is a basic question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Coded UI does not have any built-in facility for checking that a download completed and actually downloaded a file. However, Coded UI tests can use the full facilities of the language they are written in plus the **.Net** libraries.

In the Coded UI test method, at the place where you expect the download to have been completed, add some code to check the properties of the file that should have been created. For example: its existence, its creation and/or modification date and time, its size. Use the normal file IO operations to perform the checks. Microsoft provide details on [How to do basic file I/O in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304430/EN-US).

After performing the checks it may be beneficial to delete the file, to reduce wasted disc space.